# UserName Authentication web services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, security

I need to implement UserName authentication for my web service.

Currently I am considering these two approaches

1. SOAPHeader: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/authforwebservices.aspx
2. UserNameToken: WSE 3.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480575.aspx

Can anyone tell me pros-cons of these approaches?

One of the major doubt is regarding client being able to consume the service. Client is using Java, would it be possible for them to pass UserNameToken implemented using WSE or are there any integration issues?

EDIT: Also please suggest if there are any better ways (ASMX Services) to implement UserName/Password authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to warn you against using WSE 3.0. Unless you are involved in a large enterprise federated system, stay well clear. It's way too much, overly complicated and we are still trying to rid it from one of our major systems.

If you just need to use username authentication then use the soap header approach.

MSDN Link: [Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302390.aspx#secnetch10_webservicesecmodel)

Comment: Thanks Chris, Could you provide some more info on issues you faced while using WSE 3.0. So far what I have heard is its easy to implement services (esp security) using WSE. I have never used it though.

Comment: Firstly, you need to install the libraries on all your dev machines and host servers. It adds an overhead to all your web references (if you're using VS) as it creates 2 proxy classes for every service. It can work well and is, certainly, extremely powerful - but do you need it? Transport-level security (SSL) in combination with simple username tokens will give you what you need.

The biggest problem, we found, was if something went wrong. The xml configuration files are very "fragile" and rely on the server and client agreeing absolutely. Debugging exceptions is an absolute nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use HTTP basic access authentication ?
[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

cheers

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I have seen this before but never thought of this as an option. Do you have any more info on comparison with SOAP or few pros and cons...Thanks.